# IOS Touch ID Public and Private key

Tags: ios

How can I get public key touch id on the server?
Touch ID private and public keys for verification on the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Touch is only a Local authentication framework.you will not get any keys from Touch Id authentication.Only you can ask whether device is capable of Touch ID and you can ask to evaluate Touch ID.

When you evaluate TouchID, user is presented with an alert to scan touch ID.Once user completed the action, API will return the result success/failure.

If you want to send some login credentials to server, you need to save them locally when user entered first time, then extract them when user is authenticated successfully.

Here is a link to tutorial.

[Toich ID usage](https://www.raywenderlich.com/92667/securing-ios-data-keychain-touch-id-1password)

Comment: Thank you so match.

Comment: Can you please accept/upvote the answer if it has helped ?

Comment: I have generated random password and save to dataBase, verification by passcode and every time when I use Touch ID, in server I send this password and check inside of server.